# Can i connect to PHPmyadmin with Ruby On rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to ruby on rails and i wonder if it is possible to connect to phpmyadmin via ruby on rails.
I used PHP before ruby on rails and i have got all my data in my phpmyadmin  databases,so i want to connect there with ruby on rails and work there.

Comment: phpmyadmin is simply a tool in php to view mysql databases.  You can connect your rails app to a database in the mysql instance, yes.  Any changes you make you'd be able to see in phpmyadmin

Comment: @j-dexx So i should download separate mysql5 and it will work?

Comment: @TomOdell If you are able to use PHPmyadmin, you probably have mysql installed.

Comment: @Mickey I can't find it.Probably bcause i have never worked with it

Comment: @TomOdell me neither. Why not look at some tutorials. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-database-setup.htm

Comment: Understand that PHPMyAdmin is a client to a mysql service, like Firefox is a client to Stack Overflow. On your system (or your host) a mysql service is running. To find out how PHPMyAdmin is connecting to it, examine PMA's configuration. You can use the same connection host/user/password to connect your Ruby on Rails application in its `config/database.yml`.  Where mysql resides on your system may not exactly be relevant, but the hostname/user/password combination is.

Comment: @Mickey i am watching tutorial on youtube

Answer (score 0):

So Yes, you can.
But, In the sql query, you still have to put `GRANT ALL PRIVELIGES TO 'root'@'localhost'`